# Latex Error: 'stix.sty' not found

Tags: miktex, winedt, stix, wiley-article

I am using WinEdt 6.0, Miktex 2.8, Revision on 2.8.3527.
I am running the template of ETRI Wiley Journal.
Following Messagae is coming:
Latex Error: 'stix.sty' not found
Kindly help to fix the error.
I am using Windows 8.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. // Please try to be more specific. None of us can look over you shoulder, can we? So at least provide a link to the template, though external links are not well received here, as they can disappear over time.

Comment: your system is very old. Try to install stix with the miktex package manager.